# ReadProcessMemory function returns empty string

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm currently trying to read a String off of a dummy application I wrote. The problem is
that the `read_string` it returns is empty after I run everything.

```
    // Prompt for String Length
    int string_lenght = 0;
    cout << "String Lenght: ";
    cin >> string_lenght;

    // Get string size in bytes
    int string_bytes = 18 + (2 * string_lenght);

    cout << string_bytes << endl;

    // Reading pointer
    string read_string = "";

    BOOL rpmReturn = ReadProcessMemory(hProcess, (LPCVOID)memoryAddress, &read_string, string_bytes, NULL);
    if (rpmReturn == FALSE) {
        cout << "ReadProcessMemory failed. GetLastError = " << dec << GetLastError() << endl;
        system("pause");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    cout << "string = " << read_string << endl;
```

Comment: The odds that you can read an std::string correctly are zero.  Try to get ahead with char[].

Comment: At the point you're calling it, `GetLastError` has long lost its ability to return the error set by `ReadProcessMemory`.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot treat a `std::string` as a blob of binary data. Use string methods to get at the underlying character area

```
string read_string;
read_string.resize(string_length);
BOOL rpmReturn = ReadProcessMemory(hProcess, (LPCVOID)memoryAddress, read_string.data(), read_string.size(), NULL);
```

This code requires C++17 to function correctly. Prior to that you can probably use `&read_string[0]` instead of `read_string.data()`.